# Why do Hydrogen atoms become solid at very low temperature?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

When I studied about superfludity, everyone just mentioned that He4 and He3 do not crystalline into solid even at absolute zero because the masses of those atoms are very light and then the quantum flutuation prevents them to solidify. However, we all know we very well that Hydrogen atom is even ligher than Helium atom and the quantum fluctuation should be stronger in Hydrogen than in Helium, but they never mentioned why hydrogen becomes solid at low temperature.

Comment: It's hydrogen $H_2$ the bulk material that solidifies, not $H$ atoms.

Comment: But still, H2 is lighter than He3 and He4. That doesn't answer to my question.

Comment: I'm **not trying to answer your question**, merely pointing out it is poorly phrased. Your answer most likely lies in higher polarisability of the $H_2$ electron cloud, due to $2$ electrons shared by $2$ nuclei. They're more movable than in $He$.